# Define only object's key and auto generate value's type

Tags: typescript

I'm looking trying to do something like:

```
type Sizes = 'small' | 'large';

const CONFIG_BY_SIZE: Record<Sizes, any> = {
    small: {
        a: ...,
        b: ...,
        c: ...,
    },
    large: {
        a: ...,
        b: ...,
        c: ...,
    },
}
```

it works, but when i try to type `CONFIG_BY_SIZE.large.` there is no auto complete for `a` or `b` or `c`. I think it is because i define the value as any.
the values itself are quite large, so i prefer it to be auto generated if possible.

my goals is to define the key as `Sizes` but i still can have autocomplete for the value.
how do i achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some sort of type constraint, but infer something more specific than that constraint from a value, then that's what generic parameters to functions do.

So I think you'll need to provide a function to allow typescript to make that inference:

```
function createConfigBySize<T extends Record<Sizes, unknown>>(config: T): T {
  return config
}
```

What this does is maps `T` to something that `extends Record<Sizes, unknown>`. Typescript notes exactly what subtype it is, and saves that to `T`. Then you set the return type as `T` to get back whatever was inferred.

Now you can do this:

```
const CONFIG_BY_SIZE = createConfigBySize({
    small: {
        a: 123,
        b: 'abc',
        c: false,
    },
    large: {
        a: { cool: true },
        b: null,
        c: [1,2,3],
    },
})
```

Which produces this type:

```
{
    small: {
        a: number;
        b: string;
        c: boolean;
    };
    large: {
        a: {
            cool: boolean;
        };
        b: null;
        c: number[];
    };
}
```

And you also still get type checking if you use an invalid size key:

```
createConfigBySize({
  small: { foo: 123 },
  medium: { bar: 123 }, // type error
})
```

[Working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=23&ssc=3&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgLwgZygXigcmQWwIYA2BmUAPlgXgE4DmEmA3AFBMBmArgHYDGwcA9pyjcqEPMAgBhQazg0AQiHhIAPABUoEAB4TOAE1QAlCN35U9K5SgA0ULgGtO-AO6cAfG4AUpzrJoAuKDUASkCNAG8mKChRYHYqIR8-JgBfFh9kYChJAHkAOQAxAEkAcQB9eQBNMpgigC0AUXRhUXEpGTlFK09I6OjcQgJA3r7RvECARgAmAGZrKNG+gCNAzDwl7kx5xb7uQNZCZAhtvpST6MpaCGGFnfGocOF+fiGoYCp2aDPbxZWoTnYRHOiz2UAA2hNrFNrDMALrA74pYLpVoSaS+TpKRAQHoLAZEYZQVjPSazKDfaI4CB6ODsHCEpbUUkzcm2AD0bLe4GgECoVDMqWCQA)

---

That said, if you want `small.a` to be the same type as `large.a` this isn't the right solution. In that case you really should create an interface for whatever that type is. Anything you will need to reuse a type in multiple places, it's a really good idea to formally declare that interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a syntax like that to enforce that an object has a key for every entry in a union type:

```
type Sizes = 'small' | 'large';
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const CONFIG_BY_SIZE: Record<Sizes, { [key in Keys]: any }> = {
    small: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 2,
    },
    large: {
        a: 2,
        b: 2,
        c: 2,
    },
}
```

[image]

You can make this a generic type as well.

Code example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgLwgZygXigcmQWwIYA2BmUAPlgXgE4DmEmA3ALABQokUA0hCKhpnhLlMAIyFYAxo1asJAewB2yYFADCAeQByAMQCSAcQD6AIQCahmLoBaAUQBcUAEoR5VACYAeeEmQAaKADeUADaANY8UHAKXDzIALoOeAogUAC%20AHzogaxQuVC4hAQOATl5ZXgOAIy%20pWW5Ig4ATDUsdXkSTS1lqV15lLQQxbV1FVDNw2UNY71tHdPDPaypMiwaOgYm5pa2AHT9dDt4DEA).